# Adding additional lines in the title in a document that uses the apa7 document class

Tags: titles, apa7

I am trying to add my course and prof information to the title in the way the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa7) showed, but it is not working. Where I am making a mistake?

```
%% 
\documentclass[man, floatsintext, donotrepeattitle]{apa7}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}   % set page parameters suitably
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}m{\mylen}}
\newlength\mylen

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{bla bla}
\author{bla vla ksd}
\affiliation{dklfköa}
\course{sjdkkdl}
\professor{Dr. djkdlkfjlfö}
\duedate{dnkjfkflöf}

\shorttitle{Cdklslö}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For `\course`, `\professor`, and `\duedate` to generate any output when using the `apa7` document class, the `stu` (short for "student paper", I suppose) document class option has to be used, rather than the `man` option.

```
\documentclass[stu]{apa7}

\title{Bla bla bla}
\shorttitle{bla}
\author{John Doe}
\affiliation{Nowhere U}
\course{Waking Up}
\professor{D. R. Nap}
\duedate{31 Dec 3099}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

Hello World.
\end{document}
```